# c++: I want to make a arithmetic progression using array, but it gives me messy code

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;

//prototype
void fillArray(int[], int, int);
void printArray(int[], int);

int main()
{
srand(time(0));  // initialize random number generator

const int size = 5, SIZE=10;
int ar1[size], ar2[size],inc;

cout << "Enter the first value and increment for ar1: ";
cin >> ar1[0] >> inc;
cout << "Enter the first value and increment for ar2: ";
cin >> ar2[0] >> inc;




cout << "(1) ar1:\n";
fillArray(ar1, size, inc);
printArray(ar1, size);



system("pause");
return 0;

}
void fillArray(int ar[], int size, int inc)
{
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    ar[i] = ar[0] + inc;
    cout << ar[size];
}
}
void printArray(int ar[], int size)
{
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << ar[i] << ' ';
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Ask the user to input ar1[0] and inc.the first one ar1[0] is settled by user input, and the rest is increased by inc.So if I enter 4 3 ,it should return 4 7 10 13 16. My outcome is like this:
[image]

I know there is something wrong with the function fillArray but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone tell me the solution? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there's something wrong with your function `fillArray`. It assumes that the first element is initialized (which is, indeed) but then doesn't initialize the other elements in ascending order, because you always add `inc` to the value of the first element. Moreover it prints out `ar[size]` which is out of bounds at every step (the first strange numbers in your output). You can fix with this:

```
void fillArray(int ar[], int size, int inc)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        ar[i] = ar[i-1] + inc;
    }
}
```

Or you can decide to pass the first value as a parameter too.

I assume you wanted to use `size`, even if you also declare another similar variable named `SIZE` with a different value. You should also consider using `std::vector`s instead of arrays as a safer a more practical option.

Finally, in your code you ask the user to input `inc` twice (overwriting it) before using it.